# Hibernate wrong query generation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

**The query**

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from DeptLocations");
 List<?> list = query.list();
 DeptLocations dept = (DeptLocations)list.get(0);
```

**The error**

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.dept_locations deptlocati0_' at line 1
```

**The table**

```
Create Table Dept_Locations (
    Locno NUMERIC(2),
    Locname Varchar(10),
    primary key (Locno)
);
```

**The mapping**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 5, 2014 2:58:45 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojos.DeptLocations" table="dept_locations" catalog="qr">
        <id name="locno" type="byte">
            <column name="Locno" precision="2" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="locname" type="string">
            <column name="Locname" length="10" />
        </property>
        <set name="depts" table="dept" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="LOC" precision="2" scale="0" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="pojos.Dept" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**The pojo**

```
package pojos;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * DeptLocations generated by hbm2java
 */
public class DeptLocations implements java.io.Serializable {

    private byte locno;
    private String locname;
    private Set depts = new HashSet(0);

    public DeptLocations() {
    }

    public DeptLocations(byte locno) {
        this.locno = locno;
    }

    public DeptLocations(byte locno, String locname, Set depts) {
        this.locno = locno;
        this.locname = locname;
        this.depts = depts;
    }

    public byte getLocno() {
        return this.locno;
    }

    public void setLocno(byte locno) {
        this.locno = locno;
    }

    public String getLocname() {
        return this.locname;
    }

    public void setLocname(String locname) {
        this.locname = locname;
    }

    public Set getDepts() {
        return this.depts;
    }

    public void setDepts(Set depts) {
        this.depts = depts;
    }

}
```

**The configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">qr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping resource="/pojos/Dept.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="/pojos/DeptLocations.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="/pojos/Emp.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>   
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**The reverse xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-catalog="qr" match-name="dept"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="qr" match-name="dept_locations"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="qr" match-name="emp"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**The structure**

[image]

I am receiving

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.dept_locations deptlocati0_' at line 1
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy15.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at Controller.location(Controller.java:84)
    at Controller.doGet(Controller.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.dept_locations deptlocati0_' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hibernate.default_schema setting is causing the problem. It seems it should not be used when catalog attribute of class element is in use.